# Create a clickable grid in python

Tags: python, graphics, grid, structure, clickable

I'm new to python and I need a little bit of help to start my application. I want to write a Free and Open Source Application for my Master Thesis whose purpose is to solve static structures.

I have two main python libraries so far: `PyQt5` (for the user interface) and `matplotlib` (in order to show some useful diagrams once the structure is solved).

I need some functionality to let the user "draw" the structure that they want to analyze. I have thought (and given a little try) to use `matplotlib` as this "drawer", but I think that I shouldn't follow this path because this is not the purpose the library is design for. I'm explaining the desired functionality down below.

A static structure is defined through "nodes" and "bars". My vision is, when starting a project, a canvas with a measurable grid appears. Here, clicking a button, the user has the ability to click in the canvas in order to create a "node" that can be represented by a circle or some other form. This node will remain in its place until the user decides to delete it.

I'm attaching an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zCoY.png) with the objective of clarifying the explanation.

Is there any package out there that provides this functionality? Or does someone know how to implement this functionality?

Comment: I'm certain you can achieve this with matplotlib via it's `f.canvas.mpl_connect` functionality... I'll try to give you a working example but there might be 1-2 pitfalls you'll need to consider if you're completely new to python  (like mutuable and immutuable objects etc)

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a try since I was curious myself how much effort one needs to turn matplotlib into a simple drawing-tool...

Here's a working (pure matplotlib!) example that you should be able to use as a starting-point to do what you want to do.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = f.add_subplot()

# initialize your grid
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.FixedLocator(range(10)))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.FixedLocator(range(10)))
ax.grid()


# print some info text
t1 = ax.text(.5, .5,
"""LEFT-click to draw a line
RIGHT-click to remove the last point
MIDDLE-click to toggle 'snap-to-grid'""",
bbox=dict(facecolor='w',
          edgecolor='black',
          boxstyle='round, pad=1, rounding_size=1', pad=0))

t2 = ax.text(7, .5,
"""'snap-to-grid active!'""",
bbox=dict(facecolor='w',
          edgecolor='red',
          boxstyle='round, pad=1, rounding_size=1', pad=0))
t2.set_visible(False)


# draw initial lines that will be updated later
l, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2, marker='o', c='k')
p, = ax.plot([], [], lw=0, marker='.', c='r', alpha=0.25)
p_round, = ax.plot([], [], lw=0, marker='o', c='r')


# get a dict to store the values you need to change during runtime
retdict = dict(points=[],
               round_to_int=False)

# define what to do when a mouse-click event is happening
def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes != ax:
        return
    if event.button == 1:  # (e.g. left-click)
        if retdict['round_to_int']:
            retdict['points'] += [[round(event.xdata), round(event.ydata)]]
        else:
            retdict['points'] += [[event.xdata, event.ydata]]
    elif event.button == 3:  # (e.g. right-click)
        if len(retdict['points']) >= 1:
            retdict['points'] = retdict['points'][:-1]
            plt.draw()

    elif event.button == 2:  # (e.g. middle-click)
        retdict['round_to_int'] = not retdict['round_to_int']
        if retdict['round_to_int']:
            t2.set_visible(True)
        else:
            t2.set_visible(False)
        plt.draw()

    if len(retdict['points']) > 0:
        l.set_visible(True)
        l.set_data(list(zip(*retdict['points'])))

        plt.draw()
    else:
        l.set_visible(False)


# define what to do when a motion-event is detected
def on_move(event):
    if event.inaxes != ax:
        return

    p.set_data(event.xdata, event.ydata)

    if retdict['round_to_int']:
        p_round.set_data(round(event.xdata), round(event.ydata))

    plt.draw()

# connect the callbacks to the figure
f.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
f.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your answer, I sincerely appreciate a lot the effort you have taken to research and write the code.

I have tried to run it but I get an error that states:
QApplication: invalid style override 'kvantum' passed, ignoring it.
 Available styles: Windows, Fusion.

I think this is a PyQt5 error and I'm not sure why is here, since the library is not used in the code.

I'm going to do a research in order to find it out. I just wanted to thank you as soon as possible.

Comment: you're welcome :-)    I've never heard of this error, and yep... it certainly seems to be connected to how your python-environment is set up...   I've checked the script in a fresh environment in both windows and linux and it does it's job...